# View displays no results for roles without Bypass Content Access

Tags: views, users, entities, organic-groups

For some reason one of my Views displays no results when I use my moderator role, but it does when I use the administrator role. The role permissions are **exactly the same**, except for the "Bypass Content Access" permission.

When I display content of type A everything is displayed like it should. But as soon as I add a "referenced entity" relationship from A to type B, nothing is displayed and the view uses the "No results behaviour".

When I create a view displaying only type B, both roles can see everything just fine.

I'm using Content Access and Organic Groups. I granted the roles the same permissions. I also set the View permissions to None.

Does anyone have a clue why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience user1 (admin) bypasses everything , no matter what permissions the role administrator has granted (check to believe) , so just because you can see something in a view as admin and having same permissions for administrator and another role does not permits users in that role to access what admin can.

so check to see what what permissions may lead to accessing this view , this permission might be unchecked for admin but still bypassing it.